# How to confirm when user change activity in android

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an activity which is called by another activity, For example, I have two activity are Activity_1 and Activity_2. When user click on the button in Activity_1  I want to show a dialog to confrim, if user press Ok, Activity_2 will be started. Can anybody help me? Thanks!

Comment: how your research? show a little code that you try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, suppose your button is called btToActivityTwo, so you need an onClickListener event.

```
btToActivityTwo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
```

Now, inside to the onClick event, you have to create the dialog. I use a dialog library called [MaterialDialog](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs).

```
new MaterialDialog.Builder(this)
            .title("Activity flow")
            .positiveText("Go to second activity!")
            .onPositive(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
                }
            })
            .content("This is the message for the dialog")
            .show();
```

Next, inside onClick event you have to write the code to pass to the second activity, for example:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

The full code:

```
btToActivityTwo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new MaterialDialog.Builder(this)
                    .title("Activity flow")
                    .positiveText("Go to second activity!")
                    .onPositive(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
                            Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                        }
                    })
                    .content("This is the message for the dialog")
                    .show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use alert dialog to display the dialog box for confirmation. You can use the below code inside activity 1 button onclick,

```
   AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(AlertDialogActivity.this).create();
   // Setting Dialog Title  
   alertDialog.setTitle("Confirmation");
   // Setting Dialog Message    
   alertDialog.setMessage("Do you want to proceed to second activity");
   // Setting Icon to Dialog    
   alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.tick);
   // Setting OK Button     
   alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
     // Write your code here to execute after clciking ok
     startActivity(new Intent(Activity.this, SecondActivity.class));
    }
   });
   // Showing Alert Message         
   alertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

AlertDialog shoud do the job. put this on the onlclickk listener of the button

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
builder.setCancelable(true);
builder.setTitle("Title");
builder.setMessage("Message");
builder.setPositiveButton("Confirm",
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            ///open your next Activity
        }
    });
builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                ///Do nothing
    }
});

AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();
```